# notation for multiple gradient?

Tags: notation

Suppose I have $f(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)$ where $x_1,\cdots,x_n$ are vectors with the same length. I write $\nabla_{x_n}\nabla_{x_{n-1}}\cdots \nabla_{x_1}f(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)$. Is there any simple notation to represent $\nabla_{x_n}\nabla_{x_{n-1}}\cdots \nabla_{x_1}$?

Comment: $\nabla_{\bf x} f({\bf x})$.  Note the bold, vector, ${\bf x}$ in two positions.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Is it standard notation? I am a bit worried that readers might interpret $\nabla_{\textbf{x}}f(\textbf{x})$ as the standard gradient with $\textbf{x}$ being the stacked vector $\textbf{x} = \{x_1^\intercal,\cdots,x_n^\intercal\}^{\intercal} $

Comment: I would use the notation I give and *explain* precisely what it means, so your readers understand and there are no ambiguities.

Comment: Are you trying to obtain an $n$th-order derivative, or an $n\times n$ matrix?

Comment: @J.G.  It should look like $d\times d \times \cdots \times d$ where the number of $d$ is $n$.

Comment: In that case, I can't second the existing suggestion.